# Show one image in different qualities using PHP

Tags: php, image

Is there a way to show one image in different qualities on fly? ie:

```
<img src=show_img.php?img_src=http://www.simpsoncrazy.com/content/pictures/homer/HomerSimpson3.gif&img_quality=25>
<img src=show_img.php?img_src=http://www.simpsoncrazy.com/content/pictures/homer/HomerSimpson3.gif&img_quality=50>
<img src=show_img.php?img_src=http://www.simpsoncrazy.com/content/pictures/homer/HomerSimpson3.gif&img_quality=75>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use a tool like [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php) to do the compression, resizing, etc.

Second, while you have the right idea in pointing your img src to a PHP script, consider the security implications of allowing a full URL as a parameter in the request.  What if someone uses your code to point to an image on a different website with copyrighted material?  **Don't leave yourself exposed as an open proxy**...

Comment: thx, but i don't like imagick. i thik it's possible without frameworks.

Comment: @Steven Moss - no problem, consider stating your requirements/preferences up front in your question.  Also, the security issue is worth taking under advisement.

Answer (score 0):

The gif format doesn't have the ability to be output with different quality settings. When you output a gif using GD, it automatically uses the GIF87a format, which supports up to 8 bits per pixel, unless you use [imagecolortransparent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php), which will then set the format to GIF89a.

However, .jpg does and can be set in the 3rd (optional) parameter of [imagejpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) (see how to load a .gif from a URL [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php))